# Can not access single HTTPS domain

Tags: http, https, windows-8

I'm having a very weird issue with a certain HTTPS site.  I have no crazy network setup or firewalls.  Just computers behind a cable modem.  I feel dumb but I can't figure it out for the life of me.  I'm about ready to just reinstall the OS (Windows 8 standard non-domain environment).  When accessing on chrome it just hangs on establishing secure connection.  An ERR_TIMED_OUT is returned

- All HTTPS sites work but a certain one (it's a standard internet site)
- This happens on all browsers (Chrome, IE, FF)
- If I put another computer on the network it can access the site just fine so it's not a network issue.
- I put the affected PC on another network and it still can not access the site leading me to believe the computer is the issue.
- There is no HTTP version.  I made a raw request on port 80 and a Location header is returned redirecting me to the HTTPS version.
- Wireshark shows me sending a Client HELLO
- I tried disabling all AV and Firewalls to no success
- There is no proxy required.  I tried checking and unchecking "Automatically detect proxy settings"
- I tried accessing the site in a VM installed on the affected computer.  The same thing is happening on the VM.
- Yes, I tried rebooting!!!

My original question got closed however this is in the context of professional system administration.  This is an office that the MSP I work for handles as a client.  The setup is not complex enough to warrant a domain.

Comment: do you get the same ping reply ip when you ping the site from the affected computer as from others? Also check if there are any hosts defined in your hosts file i thinks it's in <windows>/drivers/etc/hosts

Comment: Like Loopo suggests, one would think malware might be at work.

Comment: Make sure you can get a response via "telnet <site> 443".  If it hangs, you need to check firewall again.  You may have a firewall on the client you are using or some type of filtering, using Firebug can help, but it appears from the description you have a firewall issue still.

Comment: Please see [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault).

Comment: Do not post the same question twice. Go back and improve the original, then Flag it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

Enable Windows Firewall and follow this procedure to enable port 443 (instead of 80 in the example):

http://wiki.mcneel.com/zoo/window7firewall

Even if Windows Firewall is not running, for some reasons, it can still block ports. I got the same problem with the ICMP protocol (which was a very basic installation of Windows without any configurations).